# Online Entry on ieee Bibliography false

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, babel, ieee-style

This is my bib entry:

```
@online{schiller_einleitung_2016,
author = {Schiller, B.},
title = {{Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger}},
month = jun,
year = {2016},
url = {URL},
urldate = {2016-09-09}, 
label = {online},
type = {online}}
```

This is the use package line

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, urldate =comp, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

This what I get

> B. Schiller. (Juni 2016). Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger, Adresse: URL (besucht am 09. 09. 2016).

This is what I should get or want.

> B. Schiller. (Juni 2016). Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger, [Online] Adresse: URL (besucht am 09. 09. 2016).

Now the question, why bib(la)tex don't put the term "[Online]" on the output as requested be the IEEE Citation Reference?

Edit1:

deleted the label and types on the bib entry:

```
@online{schiller_einleitung_2016,
author = {Schiller, B.},
title = {{Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger}},
month = jun,
year = {2016},
url = {URL},
urldate = {2016-09-09}}
```

While constructing a new MWE I found that

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=ieee, urldate =comp, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\bibliography{bib}
\begin{document}
bla \cite{schiller_einleitung_2016}
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

I get again the false Bibliography entry.

However if I comment out the line for german

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=ieee, urldate =comp, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\bibliography{bib}
\begin{document}
bla \cite{schiller_einleitung_2016}
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

The result is nice:

> B. Schiller. (Jun. 2016). Einleitung fr Smart-Home-Einsteiger,
>   [Online]. Available: URL (visited on Sep. 9, 2016).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full MWE.

Comment: I get the expected output with '[Online]' from your entry. So we really need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) to investigate what's going on. Please check the versions of the `biblatex` and `biblatex-ieee` package and report them in your question.

Comment: For all I know you can drop the `label = {online}, type = {online}` fields, they shouldn't do anything.

Comment: The Versions:
BibLaTex 3.6
biblatex-ieeee 1.1q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot},
  url         = [Online]\adddot\addspace Adresse,
}
```

that is because in `biblatex-ieee` the '[Online]' is added via the bibstring `url`. But `ieee.bbx` only defines English strings, you will have to do the work for German yourself.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{schiller_einleitung_2016,
author = {Schiller, B.},
title = {{Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger}},
month = jun,
year = {2016},
url = {http://smarthomewelt.de/intelligentes-wohnen-smart-home-ueberblick/},
urldate = {2016-09-09}, }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee, urldate =comp, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot},
  url         = [Online]\adddot\addspace Adresse,
}

\begin{document}
\cite{schiller_einleitung_2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> B. Schiller. (Juni 2016). Einleitung für Smart-Home-Einsteiger, [Online]. Adresse: http://smarthomewelt.de/intelligentes-wohnen-smart-home-ueberblick/ (besucht am 9. Sep. 2016).

Comment: Thanks, that is exaktly what i needed.
The line "andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot}" is if there is a entry in the bibliography with author= {maier andothers} to make output in maier et al. ?

Comment: @dragon89 Yes indeed, the `andothers` bibstring comes into play when a list of authors gets abbreviated either due to `and others` (note that it's two words) or to the `maxnames` setting. The default in German is 'u.a.' with this setting (taken from the English settings), you get '*et al.*'. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting the answer with the green tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: I am new on stackexchange. Thank you for your explanation how to accept an answer as the correct answer. Done.